# Are questions about syntax highlighting on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Basically what the title says. Are questions about how to implement syntax highlighting and semantic highlighting on-topic under "programming language implementation"?

Comment: There are a few LSP questions already; what kinds of question are you thinking of as within "syntax highlighting"? "How do I write a vim highlighting definition?", "How do I implement syntax highlighting in a text box in WinForms?";, and "What regular expression covers *this* syntax?" are all about implementing syntax highlighting, but in very different ways and different again from the LSP ones.

Comment: My question was going to be about correctly detecting contextual keywords without semantic highlighting. In the Swift declaration `weak var weak: AnyObject?`, the first "weak" is a keyword and the second one is an identifier. Systems that only use syntax highlighting and not semantic highlighting tend to get that wrong, and I was wondering what strategies exist to mitigate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think they should be allowed. Both because syntax highlighting is commonly done by an [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol) server which can be implemented as part of a compiler, and also because the implementation techniques used for syntax highlighting ─ i.e. lexing and parsing ─ are explicitly on-topic here.